# How to do multiline comment with conditional statements in ember.js script handlebars?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm learning ember.js and would like to sometimes deactivate some chunks of code. I know `{{! }}` works for single-line commenting inside `<script type="text/x-handlebars">`, but I can't make it work for multi-line commenting. Maybe because I have conditional statements inside.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="stuff">
    {{!
      {{#if length}}
        foobar
      {{/if}}
    }}
</script>
```

but then I got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Parse error on line xx:
...ngth}}    foobar  {{/if}}}}    {{ o
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', got 'OPEN_ENDBLOCK'
```

I also tried using `<!-- ... -->`, while the section is not shown, but I also get this error:

*Uncaught Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM*

this error doesn't show up if I just delete that chunk of code.

Comment: You will have to add an exclamation mark to any handlebars statements `{{! ... }}` inside of the `<!-- -->` comment.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Add

```
{{!--
  This is a
  multiline
  comment
--}}
```

for multiline comments

Answer (score 7):

> Any comments that must contain }} or other handlebars tokens should use the {{!-- --}} syntax.

source: http://handlebarsjs.com/

So it looks like `{{! }}` is valid for multiline as long as there are no other handlebars tokens inside it. Otherwise, `{{!-- --}}` is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio code, I used to select the part of the code and do `ctrl + /` to comment or to remove content. It will add
`{{!-- 
    Any hbs code or anything will be wrapped 
--}}`

Answer (score -2):

`{{! }}` seems to be working. Take a look [here](http://jsbin.com/olebig).

Comment: I've given an example of my non-working `{{! ... }}`, perhaps it doesn't work because I have conditional statements inside.

Comment: @HaoQiLi, I'm trying to understand why you need that. Comments are not meant to be evaluated. Why don't you leave `if` as handlebars markup?

Comment: I would like to comment out chunks of code for debugging purposes as I'm learning ember.js.  So is it true that `{{! ... }}` can't work around other handlebars conditionals?

Comment: `{{! }}` is for code comments (text). You don't usually put "executable" code in your comments, do you? :)

Comment: Not usually but if youre trying to get something to work and want to comment out a block of code without deleting it then, yeah you do.